# how to validate if there's already a field with the same registered number (Logical problem)

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, if-statement, web

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/52C98.png)

I can't let the user enter a code that already exists in the database,so i need to make one more validation for this field "code".

obviously I have to use a 'if statement' but i just can't resolve this logical problem.
can someone help ?

i tried something like that:

```
  if(cfop.getCode().equals(code){
       throw new RuntimeException("This code already exist");
  }
```

but doesn't work.

i'm very beginner,so my logical is really poor :(

Comment: What does "*does'nt work*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an (unexpected) exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please don't post code as pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA/JDBC, you can simply annotate this `Cfop.code` as `unique` in your `Cfop.class`. For example:

```
@Column(name="code", unique = true)
private Long/String code;
```

After that, you will not able to save any entity with non-unique code, it will generate error, that you need to catch with `try/catch` block in your method.

---

Feel free to ask if any of this information is not clear)

Comment: Catching that (specific) sql-error is easier said than done, at least if we want to stay database-agnostic since the actual driver determines what exception exactly is thrown. It can also be a hurdle when we test, for example, with a H2 databse, but use another database (e.g. postgres) in production; we need an implementation that is able to catch the contraint violation in both cases.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Though catching *any* error will make it easier to understand mechanism (as a first step for further development). Normal solution, in my opinion, will firstly generate a `Set` of used codes with one query, than check it for candidate and (if code is unique) save it.